# 7zip in powershell script

Tags: powershell, 7zip

I need to unzip several .zip  archives using a powershell script.
In the past, I used

```
Expand-Archive foo.zip -DestinationPath $dest
```

and it worked. But it takes a while to complete. As 7zip is faster, I added it to the windows path.

I just did `7z.exe x archive.zip` and it worked.
It also work on CMD if I enter it as a single command from terminal.

When I add this command in the script and run the .ps1 script, it give me:

> 7z.exe : Le terme « 7z.exe » n'est pas reconnu comme nom d'applet de
>   commande, fonction, fichier de script ou programme exécutable

Translation:

> (7z.exe: The Term "7z.exe" Is Not Recognized as Cmdlet Name, Function, Script File, or Executable Program)

Comment: Why not just giving the full-path to 7zip? Instead of doing 7z you just do `"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" x archive.zip`?

Comment: @maio290 Just tryed and : `Jeton inattendu « x » dans l’expression ou l’instruction.` (Unexpected token "x" in the expression or statement.)

Comment: Ah, yeah, sorry, in powershell it's `&'C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe' x archive.zip`

Comment: The suggestion with the full path is probably missing the call operator: `&`, that is `& "c:Program Files\..." ...`, see https://ss64.com/ps/call.html.

Comment: Worked. Thanks.